# How to calculate sum of numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a program in which the user enters the age of 8 guests. Each guest's age is priced differently. How can I add each cost together to come up with the total cost for each guest? This is what I have written.

```
def main():
    guest1= int(input("Enter the age of guest 1(in years): "))
    guest2 = int(input("Enter the age of guest 2(in years): "))
    guest3 = int(input("Enter the age of guest 3(in years): "))
    guest4 = int(input("Enter the age of guest 4(in years): "))
    guest5 = int(input("Enter the age of guest 5(in years): "))
    guest6 = int(input("Enter the age of guest 6(in years): "))
    guest7 = int(input("Enter the age of guest 7(in years): "))
    guest8 = int(input("Enter the age of guest 8(in years): "))
    ages = [guest1, guest2, guest3, guest4, guest5, guest6, guest7, guest8]
    getCost(ages)


def getCost(ages):
    for age in ages:
        if age <=2:
            cost = 0
            print(cost)
        elif age <= 3>12:
            cost = 14
            print(cost)
        elif age >= 65:
            cost = 18
            print(cost)
        else:
            cost = 23
            print(cost)
        
        
main()
```

Comment: I suggest you start by defining a variable to keep the total. You should also learn about `for` loops.

Answer (score 2):

You can put all the ages into a list up front by calling `input()` in a loop instead of copying and pasting it eight times:

```
ages = [int(input(f"Enter the age of guest {i}(in years): ")) for i in range(1, 9)]
```

I'd suggest having your `getCost` function just return the cost for a single age (hint: make this simpler by arranging the age brackets in ascending order, and eliminating them one at a time according to their upper bound):

```
def getCost(age):
    if age < 3:
        return 0
    elif age < 12:
        return 14
    elif age < 65:
        return 23
    else:
        return 18
```

This makes the job of `getCost` much easier -- then after you've gotten `ages` you can compute the total cost just by calling `getCost(age)` for each `age` and taking the `sum` of the result:

```
print(sum(getCost(age) for age in ages))
```

Splitting the logic into parts like this makes it easy to do other things with the costs; for example, you could show how the total was computed by `join`ing the costs before you `sum` them:

```
print(
    " + ".join(str(getCost(age)) for age in ages),
    "=",
    sum(getCost(age) for age in ages)
)
```

```
Enter the age of guest 1(in years): 2
Enter the age of guest 2(in years): 9
Enter the age of guest 3(in years): 13
Enter the age of guest 4(in years): 27
Enter the age of guest 5(in years): 44
Enter the age of guest 6(in years): 52
Enter the age of guest 7(in years): 66
Enter the age of guest 8(in years): 81
0 + 14 + 23 + 23 + 23 + 23 + 18 + 18 = 142
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by defining a `totalCost` variable, as a running total that you can keep incrementing after you calculate the cost for each customer. For instance:

```
def getCost(ages):
    totalCost = 0
    for age in ages:
        if age <=2:
            cost = 0
        elif age >= 3 and age < 12:
            cost = 14
        elif age >= 65:
            cost = 18
        else:
            cost = 23
        totalCost += cost
    return totalCost
```

Do note that I've assumed `age <= 3>12` refers to ages between 3 and 11, inclusive.

Comment: I treid doing this as well and the output shows each each cost as it is added to the previous, is there any way to get it to show just the total cost, the last line ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use function `getCost` to calculate each cost. A little bit modification of adding a variable to sum up all values will help you get what you want.

```py
def sumCost(ages):
    total = 0
    for age in ages:
        if age <=2:
            cost = 0
        elif age <= 3>12: # your original code may have some problems here. I just keep it.
            cost = 14
        elif age >= 65:
            cost = 18
        else:
            cost = 23
        total  = total + cost
    return total
```

Or you can construct a list of cost then use `sum`.

```py
def sumCost(ages):
    costs = []
    for age in ages:
        if age <=2:
            cost = 0
        elif age <= 3>12: # your original code may have some problems here. I just keep it.
            cost = 14
        elif age >= 65:
            cost = 18
        else:
            cost = 23
        costs.append(cost)
    total = sum(costs)
    return total
```